# Microsoft's own version of document-oriented database?

Tags: .net, asp.net, mongodb

recently, I have been experimenting an open source document-oriented database named MongoDB and found it fascinating.

it's super fast with dynamic schema, I don't have to do much normalization to increase productivity. It also gets along with asp.net/asp.net mvc.

So I can't stop wondering if Microsoft is going to make it's own document-oriented database?or there is one already?

a performance comparison between MongoDB and SQL server 2008.
http://www.michaelckennedy.net/blog/2010/04/29/MongoDBVsSQLServer2008PerformanceShowdown.aspx

Comment: I am very sorry, but Stack Overflow is for questions that directly relate to programming and code. We have a Programmers Q&A as well, but they do not accept questions that relate to future products and speculation. It is an interesting question, but it has no place : (

Comment: Maybe it needs a bit of re-wording, but to me "Is there a NoSQL database available from Microsoft" is a valid question. Other people are asking for tools all the time, for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1777103/

Comment: I don't know about MS's plans but take a look at http://ravendb.net/

Comment: @IrishChieftain - maybe if you like your "database servers" big, heavy, and slow

Comment: DocumentDB preview is available now on http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/ from Microsoft. Intro is here on http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-introduction/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/).  It's not directly from Microsoft, but it is specifically targetted at the .NET/Windows platform.

[MongoDB support in .NET](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center) is also excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently there is a Microsoft Research project named [Trinity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/trinity/), a graph database.
But I didn't find any information when (if ever) this will be a finished product ready for production use.

Comment: Trinity was cancelled after MS decided to work more closely with Hadoop AFAIK.